# how to get doxygen to have man pages in several different manual sections?

Tags: doxygen, manpage

What do I do if I have man pages that should have different extensions within the same project?

The Doxyfile contains the following:

## The MAN_EXTENSION tag determines the extension that is added to

## the generated man pages (default is the subroutine's section .3)

MAN_EXTENSION          = .3

In my project I have not only a C API, which should have man pages in the .3 section, but also some command line tools, which should have extension .1.

Can Doxygen handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have two different man page extensions as the result of a single doxygen run. But you could make 2 configuration files with different settings for MAN_EXTENSION and run doxygen on each one separately.